# htaccess rewrite always passes filename instead of actual url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

so I expect it to forward mysite.com/foobar to mysite.com/index.php?file=foobar
I have the following index.php file

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

no matter which url I call (mysite.com, mysite.com/foobar, mysite.com/test), the output of index.php is always

```
array(1) { ["file"]=> string(9) "index.php" }
```

whereas I expect a

```
array(1) { ["file"]=> string(0) "" }
array(1) { ["file"]=> string(6) "foobar" }
array(1) { ["file"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] also returns "file=index.php"

I don't think that any other htaccess files are involved, when I write random characters into the .htaccess file I get an Internal Server Error (as expected) and if I change the name of the parameter "file" or change the name of the file "index.php" to "test.php" the problem stays the same (displaying test.php instead of index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few bits.
Try:
Matches all characters:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([.*])$ \index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

If you only need to match alpha characters:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ \index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

If you want to make your life easier use this: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php
Or if you want to learn more about regex: https://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf

Comment: This code displays array(0) { }  when I call mysite.com or mysite.com/index.php, but returns 404 not found for calls like mysite.com/foobar

Comment: The first rule still results in the same error 404, but the second one is working just fine for my purpose. Thanks.